# Ironpython in Spotfire - draw curve and modify chart

Tags: properties, line, visualization, ironpython, spotfire

I have a code that changes my visualisation type from a Line to a Bar chart based on a property **type**. I need add a query to draw a straight line based on a property within my visualisation. The code I have so far is this:

```
from Spotfire.Dxp.Application.Visuals import VisualContent
from Spotfire.Dxp.Application.Visuals import VisualTypeIdentifiers 

vc1 = viz1.As[VisualContent]()

Yaxis=vc1.YAxis.Expression
Xaxis=vc1.XAxis.Expression
ColorAxis=vc1.ColorAxis.Expression 

if type=="LINE":
viz1.TypeId = VisualTypeIdentifiers.LineChart
if type == "BAR":
viz1.TypeId = VisualTypeIdentifiers.BarChart

vc1.XAxis.Expression=Xaxis
vc1.YAxis.Expression=Yaxis
vc1.ColorAxis.Expression=ColorAxis
```

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0):

```
from Spotfire.Dxp.Application.Visuals import LineChart
if vis.As[LineChart]().FittingModels[0].Enabled == False:
 vis.As[LineChart]().FittingModels[0].Enabled = True
else:
 vis.As[LineChart]().FittingModels[0].Enabled = False
```

This code requires a vis parameter defined as Type: Visualization Value: Page > Line Chart